# gitsharp clone http protocol failed, but git protocol success! why?

Tags: http, gitsharp

i use gitsharp,
when i want to clone project by http protocol, 
i will disappear ["cannot Read available refs"](http://pic002.cnblogs.com/images/2011/156604/2011090216183593.png)

but when i use git protocol to clone the same project frome git hub, it success!

Answer (score 1):

GitSharp's HTTP transport implementation is buggy, sadly, as is transport via SSH. Your only option is to get the code and debug into the code to find out what it is. Hopefully it is easy to fix ;)